# Unexpected Exception for selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

[error] Unexpected Exception: Error: A  element could not be loaded, or  was empty..

i am using Selenium IDE with Sel Blocks add-ons i need to perform data driven process to upload multiple record in my database. i am created xml file

```
<testdata>

   <vars 
          Field_0="Aaa" 
          Field_1="abcd"
          Field_2="delhi"
                   />
   <vars 
          Field_0="Aaa" 
          Field_1="abcd"
          Field_2="delhi"
                   />
  </testdata>
```

and I am stored in d:/data1.xml

and in Selenium IDE I am write this row

```
<tr>
<td>forXml</td>
<td>file://D:/data1.xml</td>
<td></td>
```

and my testcase. if i am running this section test suite i get this error msg

Comment: can you be more specific abou versions? Have the same on Selenium 2.8, Sel Blocks 2.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I do make some digging around it and I realised, that I'm able to read a XML file without header and under 1024 bytes or 25 lines. It is a bit odd, but with smaller file it works.